# ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: Cursor cannot be closed; connection is no longer active

Tags: python, django, db2

I am new with django and I am trying to set up db2 with it. I am following the documentation's steps in order to get this done. The database connection was done successfully but when I try to do this:

```
(myproject) C:\Users\myuser\mysite>py manage.py shell

(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from polls.models import Choice, Question  # Import the model classes we just wrote.
# No questions are in the system yet.
>>> Question.objects.all()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 250, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 274, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py",
line 1136, in execute_sql
    cursor.close()
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dbi.py", line 1145, in close
    raise self.messages[len(self.messages) - 1]
ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError: ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: Cursor cannot be closed; connection is no longer active.
```

I appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance.

I have tried to install ibm_db 3.0.1 and early versions and I get the same error.
I have installed: python 3.7.4, django 2.2, ibm_db_django 1.2.0.0 and ibm_db 3.0.0

I just changed this in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'django.contrib.redirects',
    'django.contrib.sites',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'ibm_db_django',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '50000',
        'PCONNECT':  True,  # Optional property, default is false
    }
}
```

and

USE_TZ = False

models and migrations are the same as the django's documentation. I didn't change anything else.

I expect this:

```
    # No questions are in the system yet.
    >>> Question.objects.all()
    <QuerySet []>
```

Comment: Show your *code* , i.e. the block that generates the exception. The exception text suggests a programming error in your code, specifically a cursor is already closed because the connection that was associated with the cursor is closed (or was never opened).  So, you need to show us what action might have closed the connection/disconnected, or the code that opens the cursor.

Comment: @mao I have tried again with ibm_db 3.0.1 and I get the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that django (my version is 2.2.7) calls `cursor.close()` 2 times when executing regular SQL Select in `django/db/models/sql/compiler.py`, i.e.

```
class SQLCompiler
    ...
    def execute_sql(self, result_type=MULTI, chunked_fetch=False, chunk_size=GET_ITERATOR_CHUNK_SIZE):
            ...
            return list(result) # -> calls cursor_iter
        finally:
            # done with the cursor
            cursor.close() # 2nd time call

    def cursor_iter(cursor, sentinel, col_count, itersize):
        ...
        finally:
            cursor.close() # 1st time call
```

The solution that works for me is patching `ibm_db_dbi.py` with a guard which ignores `cursor.close()` call on already closed cursor, for instance put on the start of `close()` method:

```
def close(self):
    """ ...
    """
    # close done before? if so -> nothing to do
    if self.conn_handler is None:
        return None
```

I have reported a bug to the ibm_db project: https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/453

Answer (score 0):

Earlier this year I successfully managed to get a Django site linked to a legacy IBM DB2 database. I had set it up using:
Ubuntu 16.04
Python 3.5.2
Django 2.1.7
IBM_DB 2.0.9
IBM_DB_DJANGO 1.2.0.0 (evidently pip3 install ibm_db_django==1.2.0.0a0 is the necessary command to get this to install)

I tried moving to a newer Ubuntu 18.04 environment and set up the same site. I initially had Django 2.2.6 and Python 3.6.8 installed and was getting the same error you were receiving. I downgraded to Django 2.1.7 and everything began working again while still using Python 3.6.8.

Maybe try downgrading your Django version and see if the error disappears?